# Wrong line number. Crashlytics IOS

Tags: crashlytics, crash-reports

I have a problem with the line number in the crash reports. If I run the app from Xcode the line number is correct, but if I run the app that I release the line number in the report crash is incorrect. I read something about Proguard on Android but I don't know how solve this in IOS. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. It's likely either in-lined code, closures, or compiler optimizations that are making it so we don't have a valid line number to report on.

Comment: Hi! Mike. Thank you for answer. There is something I can do to solve o improve this? I mean, I would like get the crash report as accurate as possible.

Comment: If it's for any of those reasons, then not at the moment.

Comment: I have the same issue with my project please help me out